# How to authorize token when consuming api in c#

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin project on Visual Studio 2019 and I'm trying to code my Login service.

I'm trying to consume my API, which is secured with JWT token, to login but I don't know how to do it.

```
        public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            string URL = "https://";
            var accessToken = string.Empty;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", username),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
                    };

                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);

                    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json.Result);
                        var accessTokenExpiration = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
                        accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");

                        var user = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("userName");
                        var AccessTokenExpirationDate = accessTokenExpiration;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            });
            return accessToken;
        }
```

I don't want to use a dynamic type because it won't work with IOS and it is giving me issues.

`JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(json.Result);`

I've been searching but I can't find anything so if you know another way of doing this please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dynamic`, you can simply deserialize into a `JObject`

```cs
var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var webToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
```

and then access the respective JSON property with its indexer

```cs
accessToken = webToken["access_token"];
```

Really no need for `dynamic` here.

*On a different note:* Avoid using `Task.Result` synchronously. Use `await` instead. And really no need for that `Task.Run` here.